# How to connect Sequel Pro (on a Mac) to a MySQL in a Docker

Tags: mysql, docker, connection, sequelpro

At my new job I was given a Mac (Mac Mini M1 with Big Sur), whereas I've used Windows and some Linux my whole life. First week yet.

I have a working Docker container with mysql-server and also PhpMySql.

Nevertheless I wanted to use **Sequel Pro** locally to connect to Mysql and I'm failing completely.
[Screenshot of error: "Connection failed! Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1, or the request timed out."](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CsrRl.png)

I've installed mysql-client with Homebrew and I'm able to connect with docker's mysql without any problem using:

```
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u sail -p
```

My .env file is as follows:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mysql
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laravel8vue
DB_USERNAME=sail
DB_PASSWORD=password
```

My docker-compose.yml (version 3) related to mysql is as follows:

```
mysql:
    image: 'mysql/mysql-server:8.0.26'
    ports:
        - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3306}:3306'
    environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
        MYSQL_DATABASE: '${DB_DATABASE}'
        MYSQL_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
        MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 'yes'
    volumes:
        - 'sailmysql:/var/lib/mysql'
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
        - sail
    healthcheck:
        test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping", "-p${DB_PASSWORD}"]
        retries: 3
        timeout: 5s
```

My Sequel Pro using the standard tab with the [following settings (screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jr9oz.png):

Host: 127.0.0.1
Username: sail
Password: password
Database: laravel8vue
Port: 3306

**How is it possible that I can connect with mysql-client but not with Sequel Pro? What am I missing?**

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have given up on Sequel Pro.

Sequel Ace is an open source alternative in the same style.

https://github.com/Sequel-Ace/Sequel-Ace

It is graphically the same, and it worked straight away!

Answer (score 0):

You have to expose the db port to the host. If you already running a mysql server in your device and try to running a mysql in docker means you have to changed the port number in docker-compose.

```
port:
 - 3307:3306
```

in Sequel Pro, you configuration should be like this.

```
UserName: user
Host: Your system IP / localhost / 
DBPassword: password
port: 3307
```

Comment: I'm sorry but your answer does not resolve nothing and even has errors (Port instead of Ports). The ports are already exposed as shown in the code presented in this question, and even if I hardcode. Changing the port manually wont solve either.
I can access mysql using the "mysql" command locally, so I guess the issue here is Sequel Pro that refuses somehow to connect to 127.0.0.1.